# opening the gateway setting page (192.168.1.1) in android app

Tags: java, android, network-programming, modem, gateway

i want to open the gateway setting page (192.168.1.1) in my app.  I used web view but the popup window that ask user and pass was not showing so the "401 unauthorized" error occurs.
can anyone help how  to do this? is there a way to programatically do the authentication?

here is the code I used:

```
    WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wee);
    v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    v.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    v.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    v.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.1/");
```

and the result:

[image: and the result is:]

Answer (score 0):

you have to connect your ipv4 you can find it in this way:
cmd
type: ipconfig

Answer (score 0):

First check if 192.168.1.1 is your Router Default Gateway or not. Sometimes, 192.168.1.1 might not be Your Router's Gateway which causes this issue. In most cases, 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1 or 10.0.0.1 are the IP Addresses used by Many Popular Router Brands.